# Resultado de una consulta sql/mysql en un DatagridView con columnas definidas

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

Tengo una consulta Sql/MySql que trae dos datos Dato1 y Dato2, tengo un DataGridView que ya tiene esas columnas pre-definidas con Nombre y Edad.

Lo que quiero es que la consulta se muestre en las columnas ya pre-definidas.

```
conexion.Open();
string sql = "select * from mold_info where base_mold='1191.0000'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql);
MySqlDataReader dr;
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if(dr.read())
{
    //Aqui va si la table tiene registro
}
```

Gracias.

Comment: En que estas trabajando? donde esta declarado tu datagridView? Windows Forms, Xamarin, Asp.Net

Comment: Ramiro, buenas gracias por interesarte en cuestion, estoy usando un datagridview  en C# Windows Forms

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo que para consultar datos utilices un DataAdapter, solo he usado los objetos de SQL Server pero para los de MySQL tener un objeto MySqLDataAdapter, el cual tendría algunas ventajas entre otras cosas no requieres siempre tener la conexión siempre abierta, como verás solo hay que abrirla para llenar la tabla y después la puedes cerrar

1. Quita todas las columnas del grid
2. en el SELECT especifica las columnas y si no tienen el nombre de tus columnas colocales un alias.
3. Utiliza un DataAdapter

Tomando tu código como base

OBSERVACIÓN: no tengo ambiente de desarrollo a la mano es posible que no tenga el case correcto en alguna función, siempre puedes verificar con el intelisense del IDE.

```
conexion.Open();
string sql = "select nombre_bd as Nombre, edad_bd as Edad from mold_info where base_mold='1191.0000'";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql);
MySqlDataAdapter adp = new MySqlDataAdapter();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
adp.Fill(dt);

conexion.Close();


TuDataGridView.DataSource = dt;
//Si estás trabajando web forms deberías agregar la sigueinte línea, si es WindowsForms no es necesario
TuDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: Saludos, mi hermano muchas gracias, por tu ayuda, lo que mencionas mas arriba lo he hecho y me funciona bien. la cuestion es que tengo un data gridview que ya tiene columnas. so lo que quiero es que la consulta se agregue a las columnas existentes.

Comment: Entiendo, en ese caso permiteme insistir con el uso de la tabla y en ese caso el ciclo lo usas con el DataTable foreach(DataRow row in tabla.Rows), en el objeto grid debe haber una función Add en las filas algo así como grid.Rows.Add() verifique los tipos de objetos que admite.